# reactive input not working after loading Javascript

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, shiny-reactivity

I would like to add a protein viewer to my shiny app. After loading the script my app is not responding anymore to any of my inputs. Below is a simplified version of my app using the mtcars dataset.

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
           selectizeInput("sample2", "Sample: ",
                               choices = c("cyl", "mpg", "disp", "hp")))),
  dashboardBody(
     fluidRow(
      box(title="3D Structure", width = 6, status="primary", solidHeader =TRUE, 
          uiOutput("structure_3d"))),
  fluidPage( 
    box(status="primary", solidHeader = FALSE, align = "center",
        DT::dataTableOutput("table")))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

mtcars2 <- reactive({

  mtcars2 <- mtcars

  return(mtcars2)
}) 

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

mtcars2 <- mtcars2()
mtcars2 <- subset(mtcars2, select = c(input$sample2))

  table <- DT::datatable(mtcars2, rownames = FALSE)

})

output$structure_3d <- renderUI({

  tabPanel("3D Structure", 
           tags$head(tags$script(src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-min.js")),
           tags$div(
             style="height: 400px; width: 700px: position: relative;",
             class='viewer_3Dmoljs',
             'data-pdb'='2POR',
             'data-backgroundcolor'='0xffffff',
             'data-style'='cartoon'))

})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How do I get the app to react to my inputs again?

EDIT:

I also tried to move the script to the UI but the table still does not respond to the input:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Example"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
           selectizeInput("sample2", "Sample: ",
                               choices = c("cyl", "mpg", "disp", "hp")))),
  dashboardBody(
     fluidRow(
      box(title="3D Structure", width = 6, status="primary", solidHeader =TRUE, 
          tags$head(tags$script(src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-min.js")),
          tags$div(
            style="height: 400px; width: 700px: position: relative;",
            class='viewer_3Dmoljs',
            'data-pdb'='2POR',
            'data-backgroundcolor'='0xffffff',
            'data-style'='cartoon'))),
      fluidRow( 
        box(status="primary", solidHeader = FALSE, align = "center",
            DT::dataTableOutput("table")))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

mtcars2 <- reactive({

  mtcars2 <- mtcars

  return(mtcars2)
}) 

output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

mtcars2 <- mtcars2()
mtcars2 <- subset(mtcars2, select = c(input$sample2))

  table <- DT::datatable(mtcars2, rownames = FALSE)

})

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving to this code and the javascript tags specifically into your UI.  The current renderUI() doesn't use any reactive content.  Check your javascript console as well to see if the script is throwing any errors. Below, adding it as a library that loads when you create the UI would be better form.  If you need to call a javascript function in the reactive UI, you can call the functions that are being loaded in the 3Dmol-min.js script specifically.

```
 dashboardPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-min.js")),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. It works if I move everything to the UI but the problem is that I load a local file and I would like to color specific parts of the structure using reactive inputs. Anyway you could think of making this reactive?

Comment: Glad to know it worked!  Consider adding a green checkmark.  For your broader need, happy to  help think about the design but it's hard without more code or description.  The short answer is that you might want to look at CSS definitions and to changing class definitions of objects based on reactive input.  Shinyjs has a lot of helpful functions including addClass: https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/classFuncs.html with a CSS definition of a different color (or what you need), this would be an optimal approach over re-rendering the HTML objects themselves.

Comment: I don't quite understand how I could make it reactive when I move all the code to the UI. How would I for instance change the color ( 'data-backgroundcolor'='0xffffff') based on user input?

Comment: You can use observeEvent(input$your_object_id, { addClass(id,class })

Comment: I moved the script to the UI but there is still no response.

Answer (score 0):

There's a conflict between the 3Dmol jquery and the shiny jquery.

If you run the nojquery script it works:

tags$head(tags$script(src="http://3Dmol.csb.pitt.edu/build/3Dmol-nojquery.js"))